# Why does the minimal polynomial not change on changing the field?

Tags: linear-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over a field $K$, $F$ is a subfield of $K$ and $T:V(F)\to V(F)$ is a linear operator. I think that if the field $F$ is changed to $K$ the characteristic polynomial of $T$ will change as the dimension has changed. But someone told me once that the minimal polynomial does not change. Can someone explain why?

All this is in the context of finite dimensional spaces. What will be the two analogous results if this restriction was removed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

since the minimal polynomial is a polynomial in $f(x) \in F[x] \subset K[x]$. Let $T_F$ denote the linear map viewed as map on $V(F)$ and similarly $T_K$ denote the linear map on $V(F) \otimes K$. Now $f(T_F)=f(T_K)=0$ Which means by minimality of the minimal polynomial remains to be the minimal polynomial for $T_K$

Comment: It's not clear to me as to how minimality is invoked.

Comment: the minimal polynomial of $T_K$ must divide $f(x)$. And Let $K$ as a vector space over $F$ has basis $w_1,w_2 \ldots w_n$ and $V$ as a vector space over $F$ has basis $v_1,v_2, \ldots v_m$. $T_K(v_i \otimes w_j)=T(v_i) \otimes w_j = \sum \alpha_{(i,l)}v_l \otimes w_j$ so the new matrix entries are all in $F$. So the minimal polynomial of $T_K$ is a polynomial in $F[x]$ now since $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$ the two minimal polynomials must coincide.